# Can one use data extracted from images (in-game screenshots)?

Tags: copyright, trademark, data-ownership

As an example, let's take Call of Duty Ghost. I want to take the data from the below screenshot and store it in a database as it is. (Rank, Level, Player Name, etc.)

[image]

Is it legal to extract data from a game screenshot and use it as desired? Is this related to copyright or trademark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just facts, reported by the program, and not someone's creative product, so it is not protected by copyright. The data might contain a word that coincides with a trademark, but that probably doesn't matter. Registering a name as a trademark doesn't mean that you have absolute ownership of that word, it means you have control over its use in the particular sphere, for example Apple owns that trademark for computers, but not saw blades.

Comment: I thought that copyright or trademark might not be involved, but can't the data belong to the company and only the company? Where can I find this information? Terms and conditions?

Comment: Theoretically, the EULA might have some requirement to not disclose scores, but it would have to be a pretty specific prohibition in the license.

Comment: @grrigore As a sidenote, in the US, granting factual data general copyright-like protection is likely unconstitutional, because otherwise there would be effectively copyright protection over factual data under a different legal terminology. See [Feist Publications, Inc. v. Rural Tel. Service Co.
499 U.S. 340, 346 (1991)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.): "Originality is a constitutional requirement [of copyright protection]... originality requires independent creation plus a modicum of creativity."

Comment: EA has [this](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/faq/how-to-request-permission-for-ea-games-content/). This might be useful for different situations.